# How do I delete Items from recycler view and Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a recycler view connected to my Firebase database. I have implemented the ItemTouchHelper. SImpleCallback method so that I am able to slide and the items off to delete them. My codes work, the only issue is that I am not deleting the data from the database. I can't seem to find anything method that can help my situation since I haven't used DocumentReference. 
Can anybody help me with this, How do I delete the items from the database when I click the delete icon in the on child draw?

personal fragment with the ItemTouch Helper

```
public class personalFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserID;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private TextView expense_txt;
    LinearLayout mExpense;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal, container, false);


        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();
        mExpense = myView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_layout);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Expenses").child(uid);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        recyclerView = myView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_expense);
        expense_txt = myView.findViewById(R.id.expenses_txt);
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        DisplayItemOnRecycler();


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        sumExpenses();

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);



        return myView;
    }

    public void deleteItem(){
    }


    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deleting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
            new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                    .addBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(personalFragment.this.getActivity(), R.color.Delete))
                    .addActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp)
                    .create()
                    .decorate();
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    };




    private void DisplayItemOnRecycler(){

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Expenses")
                .child(currentUserID)
                .limitToLast(100);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PersonalExpenses> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PersonalExpenses>()
                        .setQuery(query, PersonalExpenses.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PersonalExpenses, MyViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position, PersonalExpenses personalExpenses) {


                holder.setDate(personalExpenses.getDate());
                holder.setDescription(personalExpenses.getDescription());
                holder.setAmount(personalExpenses.getAmount());
                holder.setType(personalExpenses.getType());
                holder.setCurrency(personalExpenses.getCurrency());
            }

            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.expense_recycler, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }
        };


    }





    private void sumExpenses(){

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                int totalsum = 0;
                for(DataSnapshot mySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    PersonalExpenses personal = mySnapshot.getValue(PersonalExpenses.class);
                    totalsum += Integer.parseInt(personal.getAmount());

                    String stTotalsum = String.valueOf((totalsum));

                    expense_txt.setText(stTotalsum);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }


   public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final View mView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        protected void setDate(String date) {
            TextView mDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.date_income);
            mDate.setText(date);
        }

        protected void setType(String type) {
            TextView mType = mView.findViewById(R.id.type_txt);
            mType.setText(type);
        }

        protected void setDescription(String description) {
            TextView mNote = mView.findViewById(R.id.note_txt);
            mNote.setText(description);
        }

        protected void setAmount(String amount) {
            TextView mAmount = mView.findViewById(R.id.amount_income);
            String strammount = String.valueOf(amount);
            mAmount.setText(strammount);
         }

       protected void setCurrency(String currency) {
           TextView mCurrency = mView.findViewById(R.id.currency);
           mCurrency.setText(currency);
       }
    }
}
```

This is the ItemTouchHelper method in the fragment above

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deleting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                .addBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(personalFragment.this.getActivity(), R.color.Delete))
                .addActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp)
                .create()
                .decorate();
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
};
```

Comment: You'll need to know the position of the item that the user swiped, so that you can call `adapter.getRef(position).removeValue()`.

Comment: Thank you! it worked!!!